# Trying to set an event of a RadioButtonList programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, forms, event-handling

Added an event to a group of radio buttons created using `RadioButtonList()` class on page load, While trying to set the event `OnSelectedIndexChanged` of the control, but both Visual Studio and page test gave me following error:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.Protected Overridable Sub
>   OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As System.EventArgs) is not accessible in
>   this context because it is 'Protected'.

Why cannot access this event of this control programmatically and tells me that it is `Protected`?

This is the code:

```
Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)                        
       Dim group_answers As New RadioButtonList()
       group_answers.AutoPostBack = True
       AddHandler group_answers.OnSelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf check_selection

       group_answers.Items.Add(New ListItem("0%", "17"))
       group_answers.Items.Add(New ListItem("10%", "18"))
       group_answers.Items.Add(New ListItem("20%", "19"))
       group_answers.Items.Add(New ListItem("30%", "20"))                                              

       group_answers.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal                            
       question_answer.Controls.Add(group_answers)    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

`AddHandler group_answers.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf check_selection`